# I want to check if an user entered charecter is a vowel or not .The program returns true or false

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

`If the input is more than a single charecter then the program should ask the user if he wants to try again.But  my code fails and the input line keeps popping up.

```
def is_vowel(char):
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    if char not in vowels:
        return False
    return True


def main():
    again="y"
    while again.lower() == "y":
        char = input("Enter a charecter:")
        if len(char) > 1:
            #print("enter only one charecter")
            again = input("enter a charecter again: (y/n):")
            break
        else:
            is_vowel(char)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

Comment: You call `is_vowel(char)` but you don't report the result to the user.

Comment: Remove the `break` statement

Comment: To see the result change `is_vowel(char)` to `print(f'{"Is Vowel" if is_vowel(char) else "Is not a Vowel"}')`

Comment: @DarrylG the is_lower() func returns true/false whci is the requirement,not sure if i need to return a value sepaately.Could you plesaes let me know how to roceed?

Comment: @Gourab--the issue is `is_vowel` runs but nothing is done with the result (i.e. not used to make a decision or report value to the user).  So if `is_vowel` returns True vs. False what should be done with the result?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is OK, and most of your main loop is OK, too, but slight changes are needed. I added comments to the changes I made:

```
def main():
    again="y"
    while again.lower() == "y":
        char = input("Enter a character:")
        if len(char) != 1: # Changed the condition from > to !=
            print("enter exactly one character")
            again = input("enter a character again: (y/n):")
            # break - you do not want to break here
        else:
            # Print a message based on the result, of is_vowel
            print("'%s' %s a vowel" % (char, "is" if is_vowel(char) else "isn't"))
```

Comment: Thanks,this works.Can you let me know why > was replaced by != 1?

Comment: So that is the user enters an empty string, it will be treated like an invalid input, rather than a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_vowel(char):
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    if char not in vowels:
        return print('not vowel')
    else:
        return print('is vowel')

def main():
    char = input("Enter a character:")
    if len(char) > 1:
        print("enter only one character")
    else:
        is_vowel(char)
    again = input("enter a character again: (y/n):")
    if again.lower() == "y":
        main()
    else:  
        print("bye")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def is_vowel(char):
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    return (char in vowels)


def main():
    char = input("Enter a character:")
    while not is_vowel(char):
        char = input("enter a character again: (y/n):")
    print("{0} is vowel".format(char))
```